# How do I filter a data frame with dplyr's filter() and R-base's ifelse()?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

My data frame `df` looks something like this:

```
Home,     Away,    Inning
"Boston", "NYC",    "Top"
"NYC",    "Boston", "Bottom"
"NYC",    "Boston", "Top"
```

I want to use dplyr's `filter()` to make a data frame that gets its data from an `ifelse()` query.

If `Home` is `"Boston"`, give me all rows where `Inning` is `"Top"`. If `Away` is `"Boston"`, give me all rows where `Inning` is `"Bottom"`.

How do I do this with dplyr's `filter()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think you need `ifelse()`, just specify the logic in the filter.

```
dplyr::filter(df, (Home == "Boston" & Inning == "Top") | 
                  (Away == "Boston" & Inning == "Bottom"))

#     Home   Away Inning
# 1 Boston    NYC    Top
# 2    NYC Boston Bottom
```

Comment: sometimes the solution is so easy, all you need is to search for the right keyword on stackoverflow :P

Answer (score 3):

We can use `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(df1, (Home == "Boston" & Inning =="Top" )|
                     (Away == "Boston" & Inning == "Bottom"))
#   Home   Away Inning
#1 Boston    NYC    Top
#2    NYC Boston Bottom
```