# if else with filter R

Tags: r

I have a df:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  sample_id = c('SB024', '3666-01', '3666-01', '3666-02'), 
  FAO = c(100,50,3,5) 

> df1
  sample_id FAO
1     SB024 100
2   3666-01  50
3   3666-01   3
4   3666-02   5
```

I would like to do a filter like so:
If the sample id contains 3666 filter FAO >4, else filter FAO >20

So the output would be:

```
 sample_id FAO
1     SB024 100
2   3666-01  50
3   3666-02   5
```

I have tried the following after reading a previous question from here [How do I filter a data frame with dplyr's filter() and R-base's ifelse()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870800/how-do-i-filter-a-data-frame-with-dplyrs-filter-and-r-bases-ifelse):

```
df1%>% 
+   filter(df1, str_detect(sample_id, "3666" & FAO >=4))
```

Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
i Input `..1` is `case`.
x Input `..1$sample_id` must be a logical vector, not a character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt was very close but there appears to be some syntax issues; this should solve your problem:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(
  sample_id = c('SB024', '3666-01', '3666-01', '3666-02'), 
  FAO = c(100,50,3,5)
)

df1 %>%
  filter(ifelse(str_detect(sample_id, "3666"), FAO >=4, FAO >20))
#>   sample_id FAO
#> 1     SB024 100
#> 2   3666-01  50
#> 3   3666-02   5

df1 %>%
  filter(ifelse(str_detect(sample_id, "XXXX"), FAO >=4, FAO >20))
#>   sample_id FAO
#> 1     SB024 100
#> 2   3666-01  50
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>